# New icons in iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

I was trying to update my iOS app and I received some warnings about three missing icons.

> Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format.
>
> Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format.
>
> Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format.

I don't know if I have to add these icons too and where to add them or if a have to replace them for the ones that the app already has (57-114 for iPhone and 72-144 for iPad).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the new App icon sizes:

[image]

Reference is [here](http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/08/15/new-metrics-for-ios-7-app-icons).